# Как сделать нормальный скролинг странице вместе с полноэкранным?

Tags: javascript, css

Всем привет!

Мне на сайте нужно реализовать полноэкранный скролинг, но он идет не сразу, т е, есть еще и обычный, 
я попробовал использовать вот это: https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js
Этот плагин заморозил сразу всю страницу.
Как реализовать сразу и нормальный скролин и полноэкранный?
Спасибо!

Comment: Ну начнем с того что у разработчиков плагина все работает правильно, так что вы, очевидно, допустили ошибку. Далее ошибка. Мы должны определить где вы допустили ошибку. Что бы это сделать нам нужна основа для анализа, код в котором есть ошибка что бы ее найти и показать вам, после чего идет постанализное состояние, когда вы осознаете что допустили ошибку и получили ответ, который вы анализируете и пытаетесь обосновать в своей системе ассоциаций данных.

Comment: Я сделал, чтобы страница скроллилась нормально, но отсчет навигации работает не верно, допустим я инициализировал плагин для 4 секции, а навигация считает что с 1 =/

https://jsfiddle.net/sqntwo83/